# javascript auto complete performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, autocomplete

I have a custom autocomplete using javascript which calls below keyup function which inturn invokes a webservice to get results. It generates results, but when i type fastly in the field the characters are getting entered one by one slowly refining result for each character , so the final feel on UI looks like its very slow.Is there any possible way to set a typing delay so the function ACCrequestSuggestions to invoke service will get called when these is a considerable pause by user while entering on the field. Or is there any other better way to handle this using a jvascript. Please help.

```
/**
* Handles keyup events.
*/
AutoSuggestControl.prototype.handleKeyUp = function (oEvent /*:Event*/) {
var iKeyCode = oEvent.keyCode;
//for backspace (8) and delete (46), shows suggestions without typeahead
if (iKeyCode == 8 || iKeyCode == 46) {
    ACCrequestSuggestions(this, false);

//make sure not to interfere with non-character keys
} else if (iKeyCode < 32 || (iKeyCode >= 33 && iKeyCode < 46) || (iKeyCode >= 112 && iKeyCode <= 123)) {
    //ignore
} else {
    //request suggestions from the suggestion provider with typeahead
ACCrequestSuggestions(this,true);
        }
};

/**
* Generate results and create the autocomplete drop down
*/

ACCrequestSuggestions = function (oAutoSuggestControl /*:AutoSuggestControl*/,
                    bTypeAhead /*:boolean*/) {

var aSuggestions = [];

// suggestions function will invoke service call to generate results based on input
aSuggestions = new Suggestions();

   //provide suggestions to the control by building div of results
oAutoSuggestControl.autosuggest(aSuggestions, bTypeAhead);
};
```

**UPDATE :**

I used settimeout as suggested , it works well. It feels faster as i type. My websetvice data is not static data set. The webservice does the searching based on the characters i enter. So i cant cache the data on client side. So not much i can do about.

```
var timeout; // scope global
if (timeout != "")
{
clearTimeout(timeout);
}
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
//Code to retrieve suggestions
},50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to create the delay and call `ACCrequestSuggestions` only once after multiple keystrokes have been registered:

```
AutoSuggestControl.prototype.handleKeyUp = (function() {
   var timer;
   return function (oEvent) {
     var that = this;
     try {
       clearTimeout(timer); //stop timeout on key up if it's already running
     } catch(ignore) {}
     //call your code with a given delay
     timer = setTimeout(function() {

       /***your original code***/
       var iKeyCode = oEvent.keyCode;
       //for backspace (8) and delete (46), shows suggestions without typeahead
       if (iKeyCode == 8 || iKeyCode == 46) {
         ACCrequestSuggestions(that, false);
       //make sure not to interfere with non-character keys
       } else if (iKeyCode < 32 || (iKeyCode >= 33 && iKeyCode < 46) || (iKeyCode >= 112 && iKeyCode <= 123)) {
         //ignore
       } else {
         //request suggestions from the suggestion provider with typeahead
         ACCrequestSuggestions(that,true);
       }

     }, 300); //300 ms should be nice for performance and also for user experience
   }
})();
```

Please mark that this version only calls `ACCrequestSuggestions` with the last key pressed when multiple keys are hit in a distance smaller than 300ms. This may cause problems but normally there will be only one result shown to the user and this should of course be the one generated by the last key press.

Comment: Thanks mate , i am trying this change now . Will keep posted. :)

Comment: As you state this does not work and in fact does not create an auto-suggest, it creates a search on the last entry. Not what the question is asking for - see my answer and explanation.

Comment: @MartinWebb It exactly works as expected: An auto-suggest is shown with a delay of 300ms and only updated once even if the user hits many keys in a short period.

Comment: Martin , Point taken, i do have quiet a few lines of code, i will try to trim that down . Webservice is external so if the slowness is due to its performace, nothing much we can do about it. I just am trying to refine from code perspective.

Comment: If the webservice is slow you can still make it instant after the first char is typed. For example and this depends on the size of the data. You could call the webservice after 2 chars are typed, then why call it ever again? Just search the data in javascript thereafter, as you have all the data on the client!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code running here, many functions being called all of which may run many lines of code.

The place to start is to add some logic and try to thread your code.

If at all possible first wait for 2-3 character entries before doing anything, as most words need at least 2-3 letters.

Second. use a setTimeout call to wrap the main function call that does all the work, this create a thread situation where the DOM/UI is now freed. But it may not solve the problem alone.

```
// tmr must have the scope to exist across all your methods

tmr = setTimeout(function(){ACCrequestSuggestions(this,true);},300)
```

As I have shown this will reset the tmr each time the a key is typed. That will stop all code from running until 300ms after the last key press.

You can add a check to see if a tmr is set before resetting it, which will make the autosuggest run every 300ms as they type.

```
// for the purpose of the example we need a reference to our scope so we can
// use it in the function call below;

var self = this;
if (tmr) return
var tmr = setTimeout(function(){ACCrequestSuggestions(self,true);},300)
```

You then need to set tmr to undefined, in your code when the auto-suggest completes, allowing a new tmr to be fired in your type catch event.

```
tmr=undefied;
```

I would also take a good look at all the code and look to speed the thing up, if the webservice is good, this can be made to look almost instant using the right kind of strategy.

**Update: How to speed up your javascript!**

So many times on Stack Overflow i see questions regarding slow code. In this example the OP is seeking to call a webservice as fast as the user types. From the outset that will not work well.

The basics are when the user types a character say "A" he calls the webserver and does some API search on his big data and fires back a load of data, or a small subset of it. Then when the user types "P" --> "AP" he does this all over again, even though he has the data already from his last call.

First off when your searching for stuff you need 2-3 letters to get something meaningful, so that is the first place to speed it up and reduce load. Search after 2-3, this also reduces the load when the server sends back all that data.

Secondly once you get back that data in this example we need never call the server again. The searching can be done very easily in javascript, as we have all the data for results from A---> onwards.

These techniques increase the performance of your apps/sites 10 fold and reduce the load to your server, not to mention the experience for your user and your boss!

Comment: This will NOT work as the reference to `this` gets broken in `setTimeout` and will refer to `window`

Comment: My example is not a working code, it is an explanation of various techniques that can be used to speed the code and get the results requested. My answer explains how to do this in various ways, shows examples of code and the pitfalls, solutions.

Comment: I see your point but imo the OP will appreciate a complete working solution to his problem. Please also update your first example - I will retire my downvote.

Comment: I agree. And i would happily code one, but as i stated the problem is speed and perfomance. The solution we have offered may not entirely solve his problem as their are many functions we have no access to in his example. What the OP needs is advice on how to speed things up. In java-script speed is an illusion. I could make his code look like it works instantly, but to do that I would need access to his web-service and all of his code. My answer gives insights to how we go about this.